# Regular Expression to find uncommented strings?

Tags: php, regex, comments

I'd like a regular expression to find any given string but only if it is not commented with single line comments.

I don't mind if it finds the string if it is inside multiple line comments (beacuse besides I assume the Regex would be dramatically more complicated).

An example, asumming I want "mystring" (whithout quotes):

```
mystring bla bla bla <-- should find this
bla bla mystring bla <-- also this
// bla bla mystring <-- not this , because is already commented
//mystring <-- not this
//                alkdfjñas askfjña bla bla mystring <-- not this
wsfier mystring añljkfasñf <--should find this
mystring //a comment <-- should find this
 bla bla // asfsdf mystring <-- should SKIP this, because mystring is commented
/* 
asdfasf
mystring   <-- i dont care if it finds this, even if it is inside a block comment
añfkjañsflk
// aksañl mystring <-- but should skip this, because the single line is already commented with '//' (regardless the block comment) 

añskfjñas
asdasf
*/
```

In other words, I just want to look for occurrences in which mystring is not already commented with "//", that is, single line comments. (again, I don't care about multiple line comments).

thanks!

UPDATE, i've found a simple answer, and easier to understand than the accepted answer below (which also works anyway).

It is as simple as: `^([^//]*)mystring`

Since I don't care if i match only "mystring", or everything before it, that simpler Regex works perfectly.
For what I need, it is perfect because i only need to physically locate the LINES with uncommented strings (not necessarily the exact string), and then comment them, and since my editor (Notepad++) allows me to comment/uncomment with a simple shortcut (Ctrl+Q), I only need to search for the lines with the regex, jump between them (with F3) and press Ctrl+Q to comment them or keep them if i still need them.

Try it here http://regex101.com/r/jK2iW3

Comment: Any attempts to this problem yet?

Comment: no, i guess i have to use "lookbehinds" but i don't know exactly how.

Comment: @DiegoDD Well read up on it.  Try something out.  Report back here with results/questions.

Comment: tried `(?<!\/\/)mystring` but only excludes `//mystring`, not `//blablamystring`. tried `(?<!\/\/[.]*)mystring` but excludes everything. also `(?<!\/\/)[.]*(mystring)` but doesn't match what i need. I'm missing the part to tell it to consider anything between `//` and `mystring` so it will exclude `// bla bla mystring ` . [here](http://regexr.com?36n26) is my attempts.

Comment: have you considered using a recursive PCRE, first excluding comments (http://www.prestosoft.com/ps.asp?page=htmlhelp/edp/ignore_comments_options), then matchin string?

Comment: You need sth. like `\/\/` at first than everything `(.*)mystring(.*)` but only for one line and you can replace this with nothing so that you have everything else!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be able to use a lookbehind in PHP if the lookbehinds could accept indefinite wifth expressions, but you actually don't really need lookbehinds :) A lookahead can do:

```
^(?:(?!//).)*?\Kmystring
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uR6oU7)

`\K` resets the matchings.

If you suddenly want to push this further by saying that you don't want the part within the block comments, you can use some more lookaheads:

```
^(?:(?!//).)*?\Kmystring(?!(?:(?!/\*)[\s\S])*\*/)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iH0uT6)

or

```
^(?s)(?:(?!//).)*?\Kmystring(?!(?:(?!/\*).)*\*/)
```

---

Addendum:

And if you also want to get the multiple `mystring` within the same line, replace the `^` by `(?:\G|^)`

`\G` matches at the end of the previous match.

Comment: this seems to work perfectly! I 've never seen before the `\K` operator (or whatever it is). Is it standard, or it will depend on the RegEx implementation? I used it in Notepad++ to search for the strings and it works! but I don't know if it will work in other implementations, since again, the \K is completely new to me. THANKS!

Comment: @DiegoDD It doesn't work in all Regex implementation. I know it works in PCRE/PHP/Perl, will be in Python in the coming (if it didn't already come) regex module. I think it doesn't work in C#/Ruby/VBA yet, but it doesn't work on Java/Javascript for sure. Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

$example is the example you provided in a string.

```
<?php 

// Remove multiline comments
$no_multiline_comments = preg_replace('/\/\*.*?\*\//s', '', $text);

// Remove single line comments
$no_comments = preg_replace("/\/\/.*?\n/", "\n", $no_multiline_comments);

// Find strings
preg_match_all('/.*?mystring.*?\n/', $no_comments, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Result of var_dump()

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(43) "mystring bla bla bla <-- should find this
"
    [1]=>
    string(36) "bla bla mystring bla <-- also this
"
    [2]=>
    string(50) "wsfier mystring aÃ±ljkfasÃ±f <--should find this
"
    [3]=>
    string(10) "mystring 
"
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Yup, that also works. Just make sure that the removal of multiline comments is not greedy. If there are several in the file, there'll be a huge amount of characters which probably shouldn't be replaced, to be replaced.

Comment: Updated answer to fix the greedy issue. I'd use Jerry's answer though. It's awesome 8) !

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear before, but I just want the regex so I can use it in my code editor (currently notepad++) to search for text in the current file

I don't need to replace anything, to store anything, to report anything, I just need a simple regular expression to use in the "find" dialog within notepad++, and then just press "find next" (or F3) to jump between results, and decide what to do in each case.